# The foreign key fails to add a row in the child table though obvious things being taken care of

Tags: php, mysql

The following code (reg_org.php) is for registration:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!empty($_POST))
{
    $msg="";

    if(empty($_POST['org_name']) || empty($_POST['org_domain']) || empty($_POST['org_admin_name']) || empty($_POST['org_admin_email']) || empty($_POST['org_admin_pass1']) || empty($_POST['org_admin_pass2']))
    {
        $msg.="<li>Please full fill all requirement";
    }

    if($_POST['org_admin_pass1']!=$_POST['org_admin_pass2'])
    {
        $msg.="<li>Please Enter your Password Again.....";
    }

    if(!ereg("^[a-z0-9_]+[a-z0-9_.]*@[a-z0-9_-]+[a-z0-9_.-]*\.[a-z]{2,5}$",$_POST['org_admin_email']))
    {
        $msg.="<li>Please Enter Your Valid Email Address...";
    }


    if(strlen($_POST['org_admin_pass1'])>20)
    {
        $msg.="<li>Please Enter Your Password in limited Format....";
    }

    if(is_numeric($_POST['org_name']) || is_numeric($_POST['org_admin_pass1']))
    {
        $msg.="<li>Names must be in String Format...";
    }

    if($msg!="")
    {
        header("location:index.php?error=".$msg);
    }
    else
    {
  $orgname = $_POST['org_name'];
  $orgdmn = $_POST['org_domain'];
  $orgadmin = $_POST['org_admin_name'];
  $orgadminmail = $_POST['org_admin_email'];
  $orgadminpass = $_POST['org_admin_pass1'];
  $link=mysql_connect("localhost","root","")or die("Can't Connect...");

            mysql_select_db("educon",$link) or die("Can't Connect to Database...");
                $query="insert into institutes(inst_nm,inst_dmn)
            values('$orgname','$orgdmn')";
                $res = mysql_query($query,$link) or die("Can't Execute Query... ".mysql_error());
      $query="insert into users(u_name,u_pwd,u_email,u_type)
            values('$orgadmin','$orgadminpass','$orgadminmail','admin')";
      $res = mysql_query($query,$link) or die("Can't Execute Query... ".mysql_error());
                $_SESSION=array();
                $_SESSION['unm']=$orgadmin;
                $_SESSION['type']="admin";
                $_SESSION['status']=true;
                header('location:profile_admin.php');
}
}
else
{
    header("location:index.php");
}
?>
```

In the code, according to rules parent table (institutes) is created before the child table (users), the child column is identical to parent column, yet I am facing the following problem:

> Can't Execute Query... Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`educon`.`users`, CONSTRAINT `users_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`inst_id`) REFERENCES `institutes` (`inst_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Comment: I am sorry, row in parent table is created in the parent table before the child table! and not parent table created before the child table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `INSERT INTO users` statement isn't supplying a value for the `inst_id` column.  When that statement runs, the `inst_id` column will be assigned the default value for the column (declared as part of the column definition in the table). The default value could also be overridden by an assignment in a BEFORE INSERT trigger.

The MySQL error indicates that the row being inserted into the `users` table has a value for `inst_id` that does not exist in the exist in the referenced (parent) `institutes` table.

If you are wanting to reference the row that was just inserted into the `institutes` table, you would need to retrieve the value of the `inst_id` column, for the row that was just inserted.

If `inst_id` in `institutes` is an AUTO_INCREMENT column, then immediately following your `INSERT INTO institutes` statement, you can retrieve the value that was assigned.  There are a couple of mechanisms to do this. MySQL provides the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function...

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

PHP MySQL libraries provide their own functions to more easily access the value returned by this function.

The *deprecated* mysql_ extension

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

(Please note the **WARNING** in the documentation about using mysqli or PDO instead of the mysql_ extension.)